# Rotas de Áreas em ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, rotas, html-helpers

Estou trabalhando com `areas` porem não esta dando certo a rota e criei 2 `areas`, dentro de uma criei uma pasta chamada `Cadastros` e dentro da outra uma pasta chamada `Tabelas`.

**CadastrosAreaRegistration.cs**

```
namespace Projeto01.Areas.Cadastros
{
    public class CadastrosAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration 
    {
        public override string AreaName 
        {
            get 
            {
                return "Cadastros";
            }
        }

        public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context) 
        {
            context.MapRoute(
                "Cadastros_default",
                "Cadastros/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

**TabelasAreaRegistration.cs**

```
namespace Projeto01.Areas.Tabelas
{
    public class TabelasAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration 
    {
        public override string AreaName 
        {
            get 
            {
                return "Tabelas";
            }
        }

        public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context) 
        {
            context.MapRoute(
                "Tabelas_default",
                "Tabelas/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Minha duvida é, ao acessar o sistema, consigo acessar os controllers da Cadastro, porem ao clicar em Produtos da Area Tabelas, a URL tenta chamar a mesma com a Area Cadastros, nao ta alterando para Tabelas, Alguem pode me ajudar?

Layout com o menu da aplicação que chama as views

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
  <li id="liHome" role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li id="liCategorias" role="presentation">@Html.ActionLink("Categorias", "Index", "Categorias")</li>
  <li id="liFabricantes" role="presentation">@Html.ActionLink("Fabricantes", "Index", "Fabricantes")</li>
  <li id="liProdutos" role="presentation">@Html.ActionLink("Produtos", "Index", "Produtos")</li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: Amigo, você tentou algo do tipo? Html.ActionLink("Link Text", "ActionName", "ControllerName", new { Area = "NomeArea" }, new{})

Comment: Opa ficou bem lento mas pelo menos funcionou kkkkk obrigado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para acessar a rota de uma área no Asp.Net MVC, utilize a seguinte diretiva Razor:

```
Html.ActionLink("Link Text", "ActionName", "ControllerName", new { Area = "NomeArea" }, new{})
```